# Destroying instatiated Transforms from Prefabs - Platformer Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, game-engine, destroy

i m currently trying to create a Random Plattformer Levelgenerator. So i am Using Prefabs of pre designed Level Parts. And the generating of them works perfectly fine. I used the code from following youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtY_R0g8L8E&ab_channel=CodeMonkey.

Now I am trying to destroy them, when my player falls out of map or dies and load another map with the createLevel Method. But i am unable to destroy the old created Prefabs. I m getting the error:MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

Im calling the create Level function and the DestroyAllLevelParts() in a seperate Script.
Does anyone now how to solve this problem? I m not trying to reload the scene cause im currently planing on making an AI in ML Agent and just do a reset() function where i call the createLevel and destroy, when my player dies. Thanks in advance.

```
public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform levelPart_Start;
    [SerializeField] private List<Transform> levelPartList;
    [SerializeField] private Transform levelPart_Finish;
    [SerializeField] private int platforms;

    private List<Transform> all_LevelParts = new List<Transform>();
    private Vector3 lastEndPosition;

    public void CreateLevel()
    {
        lastEndPosition = levelPart_Start.Find("EndPosition").position;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < platforms; i++)
        {
            SpawnLevelPart();
        }
        SpawnLevelPart(levelPart_Finish, lastEndPosition);

    }
 
    public void SpawnLevelPart()
    {
        Transform chosenLevelPart = levelPartList[Random.Range(0, levelPartList.Count)];
        Transform lastLevelPartTransform = SpawnLevelPart(chosenLevelPart, lastEndPosition);
        lastEndPosition = lastLevelPartTransform.Find("EndPosition").position;
    }

    public Transform SpawnLevelPart(Transform levelPart, Vector3 spawnPosition)
    {
        Transform levelPartTransform = Instantiate(levelPart, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        all_LevelParts.Add(levelPartTransform);
        return levelPartTransform;
    }

    public void DestroyAllLevelParts() {
        foreach (Transform currentLevel in all_LevelParts)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(currentLevel.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because some of the gameobjects are actually destroyed during your game-play. Try adding:

```
    foreach (Transform currentLevel in all_LevelParts)
    {
        if(currentLevel != null)
          DestroyImmediate(currentLevel.gameObject);
    }
```